# Command to find graphic card info on Windows XP without using wmic?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-xp, wmic

I am calling a script remotely (using `rsh`) that looks for the graphic card information of a Windows XP system. `wmic` doesn't work remotely due to privileges. So I am looking for an alternative command that won't be blocked by privileges when called remotely.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
start "" /w dxdiag /t ~&findstr /i "chip Card Manufacturer Shared" ~.txt
```

You can find more information in the generated `~.txt`

or

```
cmd /c "cd "%userprofile%"&start  /w dxdiag /t ~&findstr /i "chip Card Manufacturer Shared" ~.txt"
```

Comment: @KH17 is there generated `~.txt` file ?

Comment: There is no generated file.

Comment: @KH17 what happens if you run only dxdiag ?

Comment: It opens the DirectX Diagnostic Tool window.

Comment: @KH17 and `dxdiag /t ~.txt` does not generates a report file?

Comment: @KH17  probably you'll have to play a little bit with this. dxdiag is the easiest way to get the video card info without wmic.

Comment: Oh actually. it did not work. I mean, it works locally but when I try to run `dxdiag /t ~.txt` remotely I don't get any output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114378/discussion-between-npocmaka-and-kh17).

Comment: @KH17 - what tool are you using for the remote call? In which folder command is executed? If it is `system32` you'll have to change it.Can you try executing to consecutive commands? it is possible your command does not wait for `dxdiag` to finish the import.You can try also with `cmd /c "cd "%userprofile%"&start  /w dxdiag /t ~&findstr /i "chip Card Manufacturer Shared" ~.txt"`

Comment: I am available to chat in the discussion room. 
I am using `rsh` to remotely access another computer. I still got nothing from that command. It runs and then after a few seconds it stops and nothing happens. This is what happens with `wmic` as well except a couple of minutes instead of seconds. Could it be that `dxdiag` also requires admin privileges?